# ReactJS passing params to exported functions

Tags: reactjs

I'm using an api to get post information, but i'm not trying to only request chunks of the data, to do this i'm just wanting to pass the range through the function - but i can't seem to do this, seems like a really simple request, can anyone help?

component requesting api information

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            posts: [],
            type: null,
            limit: 9,
            offset:0,
        }
        this.getPosts = this.getPosts.bind(this);
        this.toggleType = this.toggleType.bind(this);
    }
async componentDidMount(){
        var data = await api.newposts(this.state.offset,this.state.limit);
        this.setState({posts: data});
    }
```

and in my api request file;

```
export function newposts(limit,offset) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        var getLocalPosts = ls.get('api-request-posts');
        if(!getLocalPosts){
            axios.get(`${api}/posts?Publish=true&_sort=DatePublished:DESC`)
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response);
                ls.set('api-request-posts',JSON.stringify(response),ttl);
            }).catch(err => {
                resolve(err);
            })
        }
        else{
            var response = JSON.parse(getLocalPosts);
            var subset = response.data.slice(this.offset,this.limit);
            resolve(subset);
        }

    });

}
```

this file has loads of export function endpoints, all i want to do is pass through the variables to this export function, but nothing i provide seems to pull through to the endpoint...

where am i going wrong?

Comment: In your component, you are passing offset and limit and in the API file the params that newposts take are limit and offset (opposite/vice-versa) is that intentional?

Comment: Good spot, but I don’t think it makes a difference, I was consoling out the Parma’s as they get passed and they where undefined

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that you're not getting a response?

Comment: I get the promise back from the end point just fine, but the Params I’m passing through aren’t coming out to the end point. For example, if I actually provide numbers into api.newposts and console those params out when I reach the response ( like console.log(this.limit), they output as undefined

Comment: If you're logging inside newposts function shouldn't it be console.log(limit) and not `this.limit` because you're trying to access the param but not a class level property?

Comment: Let me give that a try

Comment: ah, i'm such an idiot - you where absolutely right mate, push it to an answer and i'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you're accessing variables in your function this way:

```
export function newposts(limit,offset) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {

        var getLocalPosts = ls.get('api-request-posts');
        if(!getLocalPosts){
            axios.get(`${api}/posts?Publish=true&_sort=DatePublished:DESC`)
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response);
                ls.set('api-request-posts',JSON.stringify(response),ttl);
            }).catch(err => {
                resolve(err);
            })
        }
        else{
            var response = JSON.parse(getLocalPosts);
            var subset = response.data.slice(offset, limit);
            resolve(subset);
        }

    });

}
```

and also a good IDE with eslint extensions will help in preventing these mistakes because it'll mark the errors with a red line.
One more thing is I would limit declaring variables with var, prefer let or const.